# How do I install IntelliSense on VS code?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, intellisense, autosuggest, code-completion

I want suggestions to pop up when I type the code, but only code I have typed above/previously pops up as suggestions. When I try selecting control space to show suggestions, I only shows the kind with the 'abc' format.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense?

Comment: I have Python, Pylance and kite installed which does most of the autocomplete